# How to concatenate word2vec generated features with VGGNet generated features

Tags: python, numpy, word2vec, vgg-net

I am working on movie dataset **scraped** from IMDB site. More importantly, i am working on two info i.e.movie overviews and movie poster data.

In the first part i process the overview data and vectorize using word2vec. I get the following features:

```
print(X.shape);print(Y.shape)

(10265, 300)
(10265, 19)
```

The second part is to work on same movies but create features out of poster images (single image shape =(224,224,3) using a pre-trained model like VGGNet. I end up getting as follows:

```
print(X.shape);print(Y.shape)

(10265, 25088)  ## image feature generated from frozen layers = 7 x 7 x 512=20588

(10265, 19)
```

I need to concatenate both the features and train a Deep MLP on this combined heterogeneous data to predict Y (19 classes).

problem I am facing that MLP requires input_shape in the visible layer. Hence i need to bring X feature from word2vec and X from VGGNET into same shape say for example:

```
 print(X_combined.shape);print(Y.shape)
    
    (10265, 512)
    (10265, 19)
```

Maybe transpose these arrays could be a solution. Or maybe create a tensor  like

```
X_combined= (10265,25088,300)
Y=(10265, 19)
```

I am still confused. Need some guidance here.

Answer (score 0):

Word2vec, alone, just creates vectors for words. Are you doing another step, like averaging all the words of a description together, to get a 300-dimensional vector for a multi-word text?

That can work as a simple baseline, but can lose subtleties compared to other methods of vectorizing a multi-word text. Also, if your word-vectors are created rom your own text data, then merely 10,265 short descriptions – maybe a few sentences each? – is a very, very underpowered training set for creating 300-dimensional word-vectors.

That said, if you have 300 dimensions from each movie text (10265 rows of 300 features each), then 25088 dimensions from each movie poster (10265 rows of 25088 features each), then concatenating them will result in 25388 dimensions per movie (10265 rows of 300+25088 features each).

From two separate `X` arrays, concatenation is straightforward:

```
In [15]: X_text.shape                                                                     
Out[15]: (10265, 300)
In [16]: X_poster.shape                                                                   
Out[16]: (10265, 25088)
In [17]: X_combined = np.concatenate((X_text, X_poster), axis=1)                          
In [18]: X_combined.shape                                                                 
Out[18]: (10265, 25388)
```

But, are you sure your next step can handle such a wide input? (Should you perhaps be using some other narrower summary/dimensional-reduction of the image features?)